# SQL Server 2008 R2 - programmatically copy stored procedure from one database to another

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am developing an app that will provide a separate database for each subscriber. When a new database is needed a stored proc on the master db fires. It creates a new db and default tables. So far so good. Now I need to copy over several stored procs from the master db to the newly created db. I do not want to maintain scripts or use 3rd party tools, it needs to be dynamic.

Right now I am grabbing the SP contents from sql_modules then attempting to exec it against the new db. Problem is I dont' know how to change the database that exec() fires against, the default db when this stored proc is run is the Master, I need it to be the target. I've tried changing the procedure declaration to `CREATE PROCEDURE [MyNewDb].[dbo].[AwesomeSP]` but sql complains

> 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' does not allow specifying the database name
>   as a prefix to the object name.

ANSWER FOLLOWS:

Arghh! This was easier than expected thanks to [this blog post found on kodyaz.com](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/create-stored-procedure-using-sp_msforeachdb-on-all-databases.aspx).  Hopefully it will help someone else.

Here is code that copies all sp's in the Master database to the target database, you can copy just the sp's you like by filtering the query on procedure name.

- `@sql` is defined as `nvarchar(max)`
- `@Name` is the target database

Code:

```
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR 
   SELECT Definition
   FROM [ResiDazeMaster].[sys].[procedures] p
   INNER JOIN [ResiDazeMaster].sys.sql_modules m ON p.object_id = m.object_id

OPEN c

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @sql

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
   SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql,'''','''''')
   SET @sql = 'USE [' + @Name + ']; EXEC(''' + @sql + ''')'

   EXEC(@sql)

   FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @sql
END             

CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

Comment: Prefixing it with Use SomeDB won't work either. I got round this sort of head scratching by creating a template DB, backing it up, and then doing a restore as

Answer (score 0):

What will work is executing dbname.dbo.sp_executesql N'CREATE PROCEDURE ...'.  So, you could build a string that does all that.  You could replace your SET @sql = 'Use...  with:

```
set @sql = N'execute ' + QUOTENAME(@name) + N'.dbo.sp_executesql N''' + @sql + ''''
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you suspect there is any performance benefit to one method over the other?  Your method might result in a couple less machine cycles depending how USE <db> is evaluated.

Comment: Oh, it's probably a little faster, but I doubt it would be very significant.  I thought the comment below the post indicated that it wasn't working, but I guess that was somebody else's experience.

I do think it's good to know about the dbname.dbo.sp_builtinproc trick because I've used it for several things over the years when I had to run from a different database than the context I wanted.  You can exec mydb.dbo.sp_help objectinmydb, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

> set @script=@destDB+'.dbo.sp_executesql N'''+@spDefenition+''''
>
> exec sp_executesql @script